# Websql queued execution - iOS6 Mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, html, mobile, web-sql

Since the release of iOS6, my web app has hit a series of bugs, one of the worst being what I'm almost 100% positive is websql transactions being queued. When I first load the app in mobile safari( ipad ), the transactions work fine.  Then, if I close safari and open it again the transactions seem to be queued and never execute.

If I open the dev tools and run a simple `alert`, the methods will fire, if I just hit reload the transactions work fine as well, or if I delay the running of the db transactions by 1sec or something it works fine as well.

I do not want to run a setTimeout to run the transactions.

Is this a caching issue that safari has now since implemented?

If anyone has ANY good ideas on how to fix this please answer below.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, initializing Facebook before websql was causing the problem. After commenting out FB the app behaved properly, which is why setTimeout solved the issue as well; the fb api was ready.  How the thread of execution gets blocked, I don't know.

So, to anyone using FB and then trying to execute websql transactions...delay FB!

Though, websql is still running a bit slow on safari load...

Comment: I have experienced this problem again when an email dialog is open and a websql transaction tries to execute.  It never executes!

Answer (score 0):

It may not be bug. You may be using series of transaction unnecessarily. You could use mulitple requests per transaction.  `onsuccess` callback, you can reuse the transaction. It should work. At the same time, limit number of requests per transaction. `setTimeout` should never necessary.

Here is how a single transaction is used to insert multiple objects

```
/**
* @param {goog.async.Deferred} df
* @param {string} store_name table name.
* @param {!Array.<!Object>} objects object to put.
 * @param {!Array.<(Array|string|number)>=} opt_keys
*/
ydn.db.req.WebSql.prototype.putObjects = function (df, store_name, objects, opt_keys) {

  var table = this.schema.getStore(store_name);
  if (!table) {
    throw new ydn.db.NotFoundError(store_name);
  }

  var me = this;
  var result_keys = [];
  var result_count = 0;

  /**
   * Put and item at i. This ydn.db.core.Storage will invoke callback to df if all objects
   * have been put, otherwise recursive call to itself at next i+1 item.
   * @param {number} i
   * @param {SQLTransaction} tx
   */
  var put = function (i, tx) {

    // todo: handle undefined or null object

    var out;
    if (goog.isDef(opt_keys)) {
      out = table.getIndexedValues(objects[i], opt_keys[i]);
    } else {
      out = table.getIndexedValues(objects[i]);
    }
    //console.log([obj, JSON.stringify(obj)]);

    var sql = 'INSERT OR REPLACE INTO ' + table.getQuotedName() +
        ' (' + out.columns.join(', ') + ') ' +
        'VALUES (' + out.slots.join(', ') + ');';

    /**
     * @param {SQLTransaction} transaction transaction.
     * @param {SQLResultSet} results results.
     */
    var success_callback = function (transaction, results) {
      result_count++;
      result_keys[i] = goog.isDef(out.key) ? out.key : results.insertId;
      if (result_count == objects.length) {
        df.callback(result_keys);
      } else {
        var next = i + ydn.db.req.WebSql.RW_REQ_PER_TX;
        if (next < objects.length) {
          put(next, transaction);
        }
      }
    };

    /**
     * @param {SQLTransaction} tr transaction.
     * @param {SQLError} error error.
     */
    var error_callback = function (tr, error) {
      if (ydn.db.req.WebSql.DEBUG) {
        window.console.log([sql, out, tr, error]);
      }
      df.errback(error);
      return true; // roll back
    };

    //console.log([sql, out.values]);
    tx.executeSql(sql, out.values, success_callback, error_callback);
  };

  if (objects.length > 0) {
    // send parallel requests
    for (var i = 0; i < ydn.db.req.WebSql.RW_REQ_PER_TX && i < objects.length; i++) {
      put(i, this.getTx());
    }
  } else {
    df.callback([]);
  }
};
```

Regarding transaction queue, it is better to handle by the application rather than by the SQLite for robustness. Basically we can watch transaction `complete` event before starting a new transaction. It is also fine to run multiple transactions as long as they are under control. Out of control will be opening transactions under a loop. Generally I will open only couple of transactions.

Here is how transaction is queued:

```
/**
 * Create a new isolated transaction. After creating a transaction, use
 * {@link #getTx} to received an active transaction. If transaction is not
 * active, it return null. In this case a new transaction must re-create.
 * @export
 * @param {Function} trFn function that invoke in the transaction.
 * @param {!Array.<string>} store_names list of keys or
 * store name involved in the transaction.
 * @param {ydn.db.TransactionMode=} opt_mode mode, default to 'readonly'.
 * @param {function(ydn.db.TransactionEventTypes, *)=} oncompleted
 * @param {...} opt_args
 * @override
 */
ydn.db.tr.TxStorage.prototype.transaction = function (trFn, store_names, opt_mode, oncompleted, opt_args) {

  //console.log('tr starting ' + trFn.name);
  var scope_name = trFn.name || '';

  var names = store_names;
  if (goog.isString(store_names)) {
    names = [store_names];
  } else if (!goog.isArray(store_names) ||
    (store_names.length > 0 && !goog.isString(store_names[0]))) {
    throw new ydn.error.ArgumentException("storeNames");
  }
  var mode = goog.isDef(opt_mode) ? opt_mode : ydn.db.TransactionMode.READ_ONLY;
  var outFn = trFn;
  if (arguments.length > 4) { // handle optional parameters
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 4);
    outFn = function () {
      // Prepend the bound arguments to the current arguments.
      var newArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
       //newArgs.unshift.apply(newArgs, args); // pre-apply
      newArgs = newArgs.concat(args); // post-apply
      return trFn.apply(this, newArgs);
    }
  }
  outFn.name = scope_name;

  var me = this;

  if (this.mu_tx_.isActive()) {
    //console.log(this + ' active')
    this.pushTxQueue(outFn, store_names, mode, oncompleted);
  } else {
    //console.log(this + ' not active')
    var transaction_process = function (tx) {

      me.mu_tx_.up(tx, scope_name);

      // now execute transaction process
      outFn(me);

      me.mu_tx_.out(); // flag transaction callback scope is over.
      // transaction is still active and use in followup request handlers
    };

    var completed_handler = function (type, event) {
      me.mu_tx_.down(type, event);
      /**
       * @preserve_try
       */
      try {
        if (goog.isFunction(oncompleted)) {
          oncompleted(type, event);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        // swallow error. document it publicly.
        // this is necessary to continue transaction queue
        if (goog.DEBUG) {
          throw e;
        }
      } finally {
        me.popTxQueue_();
      }
    };

    if (ydn.db.tr.TxStorage.DEBUG) {
      window.console.log(this + ' transaction ' + mode + ' open for ' + JSON.stringify(names) + ' in ' + scope_name);
    }
    this.storage_.newTransaction(transaction_process, names, mode, completed_handler);
  }

};
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using a single transaction to execute multiple requests. As stated in my question, this problem was NOT introduced until iOS6 and works fine if I delay the transaction calls or reload the page.  It only happens if the page loads from a closed safari.

Comment: I see. My guess was iOS6 tighten up request. It may be other reasons. A few source code might help to see the problem.